# How do I parse data from a JSON file and save it to another text file in shell script

Tags: json, shell, parsing

Suppose I have this JSON file,

```json
{
   "tags": [
    {
      "name": "xxx1",
      "image_id": "yyy1"
    },


    {
      "name": "xxx2",
      "image_id": "yyy2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse just the values from key 'name' and save it to another text file example.txt.

My desired output in the text file would be

```
xxx1

xxx2
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '.tags[].name' input.json > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in temp.json and use the below command.

`cat temp.json | grep name | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d "," -f 1 >> output.txt`

Comment: This is an extremely specific solution and only works if (1) the JSON is multi-line; (2) values don't contain arrays or sub-objects; (3) neither keys nor values contain colons or commas.

Comment: Recommend qualifying this answer so that the OP understands the narrow domain in which it applies.